# How to provide better logging approach for library class in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby on rails application. I am writing a client for external service. I want to do a better logging instead of writing more log statements and handle exceptions in each methods of a class like as below.

I am not using model or controller. It is a class in app/lib folder?

What is the best way to avoid more log statements for this scenario?

Also It would be helpful if any custom log formatter references

Here is my client

app/lib/client.rb

```
class ExternalClient
 def initialize
   @client = ExternalService.new("<host>", "<username>", "<password>")
   @logger = Logger.new("log/client.log")
 end

 def customer
   begin
     @logger.info "Fetching customers"
     customers = @client.get_customers
     @logger.info "Response: #{customers}"
   rescue StandardError => e
     @logger.error "#{e.message} + "\n" + #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
   end
 end

 def products
   begin
     @logger.info "Fetching products"
     products = @client.get_products
     @logger.info "Response: #{products}"
   rescue StandardError => e
     @logger.error "#{e.message} + "\n" + #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
   end
 end

 def customer_address(customer_name)
   begin
     @logger.info "Fetching customer address"
     raise "Customer #{customer_name} not found" if @client.get_customers(customer_name)
     address = @client.get_customers(customer_name)
     @logger.info "Customer address #{address} for #{customer_name} customer"
   rescue StandardError => e
     @logger.error "#{e.message} + "\n" + #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: You are writing custom logs.Whatever you do you will always have to pass messages as arguments. You. might get some idea from https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-custom-logger-in-rails/

Comment: What does _What is the best way to avoid more log statements for this scenario?_ mean? You want us to look at your code and remove some of your calls to `@logger`?